# Functional document preparation for xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, documentation-generation

I have to prepare functional documentation for objective-c class methods like below example.

```
/*!
 @function       getEmployeeDetails

 @abstract       getEmployeeDetails

 @discussion     This function will fetch employee details based on employee id

 @param          strEmpId 

 employee unique id

 @result         an Array of Employee

 */

-(void)getEmployeeDetails :(nsstring *)strEmpId{
}
```

I referred to [HeaderDoc User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH346-CHDJFEGF) in the below link and got idea how to prepare manually

Is there any short cut keys for functional documents?

Comment: are you just asking how to run the headerDoc script to produce your documentation?

Comment: yes, and i got such stuff through VVDocumenter provided by rdurand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VVDocumenter](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) :

> Writing document is so important for developing, but it is really
>   painful with Xcode. Think about how much time you are wasting in
>   pressing '*' or '/', and typing the parameters again and again. Now,
>   you can find the method (or any code) you want to document to, and
>   type in ///, the document will be generated for you and all params and
>   return will be extracted into a Javadoc style, which is compatible
>   with appledoc, Doxygen and HeaderDoc. You can just fill the inline
>   placeholder tokens to finish your document.

After running the project with Xcode, in any project, you can generate the documentation by typing "///" (you can change this string in the settings) :

[image]